# How to generate multiple parse trees for an ambiguous sentence in NLTK?

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk

I have the following code in Python.

```
sent = [("very","ADJ"),("colourful","ADJ"),("ice","NN"),("cream","NN"),("van","NN")] 
patterns= r"""
  NP:{<ADJ>*<NN>+}  

"""
NPChunker=nltk.RegexpParser(patterns) # create chunk parser
for s in NPChunker.nbest_parse(sent):
    print s.draw()
```

The output is:

```
(S (NP very/ADJ colourful/ADJ ice/NN cream/NN van/NN))
```

But the output should have another 2 parse trees.

```
(S (NP very/ADJ colourful/ADJ ice/NN) (NP cream/NN) (NP van/NN))
(S (NP very/ADJ colourful/ADJ ice/NN cream/NN) van/NN)
```

The problem is that only the first regular expression is taken by the RegexpParser. How can I generate all possible parse trees at once?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible with the RegexpParser class. It inherits the nbest_parse method from the ParserI interface, and looking at the source code (https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/master/nltk/parse/api.py) it can be seen that it just defaults to running the parse method of the base class and returning that as an iterable.

As someone tried to explain in [Chunking with nltk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692489/chunking-with-nltk), the chunking classes are not the tool to use for this purpose (yet!), have a look at http://nltk.org/book/ch08.html, there are some quick examples, which would only take you halfway with what you want to achieve, necessitating a lot of pre-processing and smart design.